# File path insert multiple rows MySQL and Php

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently able to perform an upload of multiple images and then inserting the file paths into a row in the database. Ideally I need to find a way to upload these files paths as separate entries with their own ID. The reason why is because the image paths I am inserting are to be bound to a task which is inserted into a separate table.

```
function upload_file_new_task(){

global $db;

if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $path = "../uploads/";
    for ($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {
        $ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]));
        $path = $path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1]; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO upload_data (`image`) VALUES ('$path');";
    $res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    echo "<p>Post Created $date</p>";
}

}
```

So theimage is uploaded into the /uploads folder, the path is then loaded into the database as a single row with an id in the `ID` field and the path(s) are loaded into the `image` field.

Comment: Use query in for loop...

Comment: Aha as simple as that! Makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: Posted an answer also... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
function upload_file_new_task()
{    
global $db;

if(isset($_POST['create'])) 
{
 $path = "../uploads/";
 for ($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) 
 {
   $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $path1 = $path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext; 
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $path1);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO upload_data (`image`) VALUES ('$path1');";
   $res = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 }
 echo "<p>Post Created $date</p>";
}

}
```

Comment: There is one slight issue here, its creating multiple rows, however its posting all of the images into the same field still but just creating multiple instances of it

Comment: `I need to find a way to upload these files paths as separate entries with their own ID` those were your words...

Comment: Yes but you are being very literal, what use would that be? They need to be separated out into rows so each path is its own row.

Comment: Actually i am not getting you maybe you need to add an extra field witch will contain your another table's some row id... like post_id or something like this....

Comment: I will try and explain, so currently all of the upload paths are being inserting into 1 row without any separation, I need to upload multiple images into separate rows from one insert query. If I include the SQL into the loop it creates multiple rows but each row still contains all of the files paths but I need those separating out into each of the rows it has created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108689/discussion-between-dan-and-praveen-kumar).